# Using a library in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, mandrill, php-7.2

Im trying to use the [Mandrill API](https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/) with the Symfony framework. I installed the API using composer (`composer require mandrill/mandrill`). This places the library in the `/vendor` directory but Im having trouble actually using the `Mandrill` class in my service.

```
<?php

namespace App\Services;

use App\Services\Utilities;

class Email {

    public function __construct($mandrill_api_key, Utilities $u){

        $mandrill = new Mandrill($this->mandrill_api_key); // throws exception
    }
}
```

The error I get is as follows: "Attempted to load class "Mandrill" from namespace "App\Services".
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?"

Obviously, its trying to load the Mandrill class from the Services namespace. But I need that namespace to load the `Utilities` service.

I tried adding the line `use Mandrill\Mandrill` - to load that mandrill class from the mandrill directory in vendor, but this throws the same namespace error but for the Mandrill namespace.

The API documentation has the following:

```
<?php
    require_once 'mandrill-api-php/src/Mandrill.php'; //Not required with Composer
    $mandrill = new Mandrill('YOUR_API_KEY');
?>
```

`require_once` is how I included this class previously in php 5.x but I not able to include it in symfony/php 7.x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to access a classname from the root namespace you need to prepend it with a backslash:

```
new \Mandrill(...)
```

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.global.php